# java plugin specification via properties file

Tags: java, plugins

I have a project which I want to add plugins. I have all the interfaces/factories/etc. setup (my gateway interface is called `ApplicationMonitorFactory`), I just need to make a way to locate/activate the plugin. My configuration file is a java properties file.

I think what I need to do is:

1. find a good way to specify a set of one or more plugins
2. for each plugin, run it

---

### 1. find a good way to specify a set of one or more plugins

something like:

```
application.plugins=foo-monitor.jar,bar-monitor.jar
```

I think maybe it's just best to specify a list of jar files; for each jar file specified, the implication is that it contains one or more classes which implement `ApplicationMonitorFactory`, and these are the ones that will be instantiated. (I might also add an annotation `@ApplicationMonitorPlugin` so that a .jar file can have a test ApplicationMonitorFactory that does not get instantiated)

**Does this sound reasonable?**

---

### 2. for each plugin, run it

I did this once a while back, and if I remember right I think I need to use a custom classloader to add the appropriate .jar file to the classpath dynamically. Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could I suggest using OSGI instead? If it's a serverside project, something like [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) gives you quite a lot out of the box in terms of plugin deployment and specification.

To answer the questions based on what you have at the moment:

### 1. find a good way to specify a set of one or more plugins

The properties file approach is fine. You may want to just be able to drop plugins into a folder that you monitor if you want hot deploy. Just having 1 jar file for a plugin does limit plugin developers to packaging all of their dependencies into a single jar file (maven shade plugin is useful for this). The annotation approach should work (the approach that Servlet 3.0 uses). Using OSGI, you'd have a manifest file with a Bundle-Activator property that would reference the plugin class that should be instantiated.

### 2. for each plugin, run it

Yes, you would need to fire up a class loader for the Jar files. This is where things get a bit hairier. It's easy enough to do but Class loading has all sorts of gotcha's. This is where OSGI would really help, even though it is a bit of an upfront cost.